# Como deixar gráfico dinâmico com Google charts?

Tags: php, javascript, google-charts

Estou com um problema em plotar meu gráfico de linhas utilizando google charts, quando ele faz a busca no bando e popula meu gráfico o mesmo não retira o valor mais antigo, assim fica inserindo e poluindo de dados o gráfico.

Utilizei o MAX e MIN dentro das Options e nada foi feito.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(draw);
        function draw(){
            drawBackgroundColor();
            drawToolbar();
        }
        function drawBackgroundColor(){
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
              var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

              data.addColumn('string', 'Horario');
              data.addColumn('number', 'Central');
              data.addColumn('number', 'Sala Baterias');
              data.addColumn('number', 'Nobreak');

              data2.addColumn('string', 'Horario');
              data2.addColumn('number', 'Central');
              data2.addColumn('number', 'Sala Baterias');
              data2.addColumn('number', 'Nobreak');
            
              //Captura os dados em JSON e monta o gráfico, de acordo com os dados.
              data.addRows( <?php echo $jsonTable ?>);
              data2.addRows( <?php echo $jsonTable2 ?>);


              //Opções do gráfico:  
              var options = {
                chart: {
                  title: 'Temperatura',
                },
                hAxis: {
                  title: 'Hora',
                  viewWindow: {

                    //min: 9,
                    //max: 16
                  }
                  
                },
                vAxis: {
                  title: 'Temperatura'
                },
                focusTarget : 'category',
                explorer: {
                actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                axis: 'horizontal',
                
                keepInBounds: true,
                maxZoomIn: 4.0,
                maxZoomOut: 4.0
              }, 
              animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'in'
              },
                colors: ['#a52714', '#097138', 'blue'],

                //pointsVisible: true
              };

              

              var options2 = {
                chart: {
                  title: 'Umidade',
                },
                hAxis: {
                  title: 'Hora'
                },
                vAxis: {
                  title: 'umidade'
                },
                colors: ['#a52714', '#097138', 'blue'],

                
              };


              var tempChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
              google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(tempChart, 'ready', function () {
                    
                    var umiChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
                    umiChart.draw(data2, options2);
                });
              tempChart.draw(data, options);

        } 
      </script>
```

Queria que ele ficasse com uma especie de animação(até porque não vai ter interação nele, somente monitoração), em que, a cada select no banco o gráfico "corria" as linhas, olhei a documentação de adicionar e eliminar rows, mas não consegui sucesso. Abaixo segue o JavaScript que utilizo.

Comment: Para alguns falta tompero. Para você, acho que está faltando um pouquinho de [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou deixar um exemplo de como eu faço esse tipo de população de charts do Google:
Geralmente populo utilizando um a conexão com o banco de dados, mas é possível fazer isso utilizando uma array e um foreach:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Estado', 'Valor'],

<?php 

$estados=array("São Paulo"=>"15","Minas Gerais"=>"10","Bahia"=>"23");

foreach ($estados as $estado => $valor) {
    echo "['".$estado."',  ".$valor."],";
}

?>

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Basicamente o que esse código faz é incluir uma extrusão dos dados da **array** e exibir no formato utilizado pelo js do Google Charts. Por conta do **foreach**, enquanto houver informações na array ele continuará o loop escrevendo os dados contidos na array dentro do próprio script JS do Chart.

Esse método que usei acima tb é válido para informações retornadas em json, porém antes de utilizar o foreach, no caso do **json** talvez seja necessário utilizar um **json_decode** para recuperar as informações. Se precisar ver os dados para poder escrever seu script, utilize um **var_dump()**.

Para você entender como foi a adaptação, da uma olhada no mesmo script, porém original que a google deixa disponível, e veja onde exatamente eu coloquei o php para popular as entradas (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado, precisava exatamente disso.